# Get browser zooming value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find the zooming percentage(ex:zooming 110%) value When we perform the zooming with keyboard and mouse scroll in chrome browser.

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers

Comment: Chrome uses Webkit, btw.